# How to un-nest SCSS

Tags: sass, zendesk

I have a scss file that includes nested styles. The file is intended to end up as the style sheet for Zendesk. Zendesk allows you to use scss like variables, and color functions, however, it does *not* allow you to use nested style declarations. Is there a way that I can un-nest the styles, while leaving variables and color functions as they are? I have tried looking for a "flatten" function to no avail.

For example:

**Input**

```
.footer {
  .footer-language-selector {
    color: lighten($color_3, 20%);
  }
}
```

**Desired Output** Note: both the variable and the color function remain as in the input

```
.footer .footer-language-selector {
  color: lighten($color_3, 20%);
}
```

Comment: You might have a look at `@at-root`. I however not totally sure it will help in your case.

Comment: @Simplicius, my understanding is that ignores nesting rather than un-nesting, but its an interesting idea, thanks for your help